# Disambiguate [kde] from [kernel-density]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

**Update 2022-03-24:** Assuming Larnu's proposal has reached consensus:

1. **[retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)** — [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) questions should be retagged as:

   - [kde-plasma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma) for KDE Plasma questions
   - [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density) for kernel density estimation questions
   - or closed if needed
2. **[synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)** — "kde" should be added as a synonym under [tags/kde-plasma/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kde-plasma/synonyms)

---

"KDE" has two main meanings on SO:

| Tag | Context | Questions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) | [KDE ecosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) | 700+ |
| [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density) | [Kernel density estimation (KDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) | 500+ |

**~10% of [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) questions are really about [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density)** (based on the first few [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) pages).

---

How can we reduce [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density) mix-ups?

1. Should we reword the excerpt of [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) with caveats?

   > NOT FOR KERNEL DENSITY ESTIMATION. Use this tag only if your question relates to the Unix graphical desktop environment. For kernel density questions, use [kernel-density].
2. Should we rename [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) to something like [kde-de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-de) or [kde-desktop-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-desktop-environment)?
3. Should we rename [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density) to something like [kde-kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-kernel-density)?
4. Other ideas?

Comment: There don't seem to be any objections to Larnu's answer. How do we proceed from here? Is it fine to just start retagging [tag:kde] questions into [tag:kde-plasma] or [tag:kernel-density] (or closing) as needed?

Comment: Someone with sufficient reputation and tag score can [suggest a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kde-plasma/synonyms) and then it needs to be approved somehow. I think suggesting the synonym on kde-plasma is the correct place to make all kde tags be renamed to kde-plasma

Comment: Yes I meant in addition to what you mentioned in your comment we need to add a synonym

Comment: I would close several kde questions just from the get go

Comment: what about using kool-desktop-environment instead of kde

Comment: @user12646409 It seems they've rebranded away from that name: [*"The K doesn't stand for anything - only a few rumours exist of what the K originally stood for. At the moment, we consider KDE to stand by itself - the DE doesn't mean anything anymore either."*](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=122508#p318032)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, I think that renaming [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density) to [kde-kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-kernel-density) isn't correct; this won't solve the problem of people using [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) for kernel density.

In regards to [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) the information on the tag is a little confusing. The excerpt states:

> KDE is a powerful graphical desktop environment for Unix workstations.

On the other hand the info states:

> KDE is an international free software community producing an integrated set of cross-platform applications designed to run on Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, Microsoft Windows, and OS X systems. It is known for its Plasma Desktop, a desktop environment provided as the default working environment on many Linux distributions, such as openSUSE, Mageia and Kubuntu and is the default desktop environment on PC-BSD, a BSD operating system

The info page clearly notes that KDE does more than make a Desktop environment, but the excerpt implies the tag is just about their desktop environment (which is called Plasma). If [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) is about the *company* KDE, then this is like tagging [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft); which isn't a good tag for Stack Overflow (and the example tag doesn't exist for good reason).

As such, if the tag [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) is actually meant to be about KDE's Desktop Environment, Plasma, then the tag should be renamed to [kde-plasma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma) and the info page updated to reflect that. This does mean that the questions will need to be checked to ensure that they aren't about a different KDE product (such as Krita), and retagged appropriately too, or voted to be closed if they are off-topic.

---

As 2 new tags have been added to the question, I thought I'd quickly put my thoughts on those.

[kde4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde4) *probably* doesn't need addressing. I doubt that confusion is going to occur between [kde4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde4) and [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density).

As for the existence of [kde-plasma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma), then [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) should likely be merged into [kde-plasma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde-plasma) and then [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) made a synonym of it. If someone then goes to use [kde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kde) when they want to ask about [kernel-density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-density), then the tag would be changed, and *hopefully* they would correct their tag. If they don't, I don't think there's any amount of handholding that could stop that person using the incorrect tag.

Comment: I see, I'm not too familiar with DEs and wasn't aware of the distinction. So you're saying KDE doesn't actually correspond 1:1 with GNOME; it's actually KDE Plasma vs GNOME?

Comment: KDE plasma isn't based on Gnome at all, @tdy . It's another alternative like LXQt (which Lubuntu uses as it's default desktop environment).

Comment: That's not what I meant. Let me rephrase: Lots of Linux techblogs compare [GNOME vs KDE](https://www.google.com/search?q=desktop+environment+gnome+vs+kde). If I understand your distinction correctly, they should technically be comparing "GNOME vs KDE Plasma" instead?

Comment: Technically speaking, yes. Just many will synonymise KDE with KDE Plasma when talking about desktop environments; myself included. From an accurate tagging perspective though, and to disambiguate, them [[tag:kde-plasma]] fulfils both.

Comment: I didn't mean [tag:kde4] is related to [tag:kernel-density], just that it's related to the retagging of Plasma questions overall. I've updated the question text to clarify.

Comment: Version tags would be a little outside of the scope, @tdy . It depends on the domain, but version specific tags should either be used when using functionality specific to a version (this is [[tag:python]]'s preference) or in addition to the main tag to denote the version the OP is using (this is [[tag:sql-server]]'s preference). [[tag:kde4]] doesn't need disambiguation, but that doesn't mean I'm against it being renamed to [[tag:kde-plasma4]]; it's just that the it's not part of the problem.

Comment: Ah understood, the potential [tag:kde-plasma-4] vs [tag:kde-plasma-5] issue can be addressed entirely separate to the kernel density issue.

Comment: Yes, exactly, @tdy .

Comment: For a developer standpoint, they don't care if you are using kde2, 3, 4, 5 or X. They use kde frameworks or qt. The later exists as tag. We don't need a tag for a DE, only for the libraries that developers use.

Comment: Didn't touch [kde4], but added a synonym as outlined above. I would suggest discussing the other KDE tags in a separate question

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help @Machavity